# How Can I Make SHA256withRSA in PHP? How i can know what [signature bytes] in official example?

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth

How can I make SHA256withRSA in PHP?

example:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

```
   {"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}.
    {
    "iss":"761326798069-r5mljlln1rd4lrbhg75efgigp36m78j5@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction",
    "aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
    "exp":1328554385,
    "iat":1328550785
    }.
    [signature bytes]
```

---

Below is an example of a JWT that has been signed and is ready for transmission:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiI3NjEzMjY3OTgwNjktcjVtbGpsbG4xcmQ0bHJiaGc3NWVmZ2lncDM2bTc4ajVAZGV2ZWxvcGVyLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC5jb20iLCJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL2F1dGgvcHJlZGljdGlvbiIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL29hdXRoMi92NC90b2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTMyODU1NDM4NSwiaWF0IjoxMzI4NTUwNzg1fQ.UFUt59SUM2_AW4cRU8Y0BYVQsNTo4n7AFsNrqOpYiICDu37vVt-tw38UKzjmUKtcRsLLjrR3gFW3dNDMx_pL9DVjgVHDdYirtrCekUHOYoa1CMR66nxep5q5cBQ4y4u2kIgSvChCTc9pmLLNoIem-ruCecAJYgI9Ks7pTnW1gkOKs0x3YpiLpzplVHAkkHztaXiJdtpBcY1OXyo6jTQCa3Lk2Q3va1dPkh_d--GU2M5flgd8xNBPYw4vxyt0mP59XZlHMpztZt0soSgObf7G3GXArreF_6tpbFsS3z2t5zkEiHuWJXpzcYr5zWTRPDEHsejeBSG8EgpLDce2380ROQ
```

How do I check what [signature bytes]? How do I make SHA256withRSA in PHP?:

> Sign the UTF-8 representation of the input using SHA256withRSA (also
>   known as RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN with the SHA-256 hash function)

Answer (score 11):

You can use the PHP function [openssl_sign()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php):

```
//helper function
function base64url_encode($data) { 
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
}

//Google's Documentation of Creating a JWT: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests

//{Base64url encoded JSON header}
$jwtHeader = base64url_encode(json_encode(array(
    "alg" => "RS256",
    "typ" => "JWT"
)));
//{Base64url encoded JSON claim set}
$now = time();
$jwtClaim = base64url_encode(json_encode(array(
    "iss" => "761326798069-r5mljlln1rd4lrbhg75efgigp36m78j5@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction",
    "aud" => "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
    "exp" => $now + 3600,
    "iat" => $now
)));
//The base string for the signature: {Base64url encoded JSON header}.{Base64url encoded JSON claim set}
openssl_sign(
    $jwtHeader.".".$jwtClaim,
    $jwtSig,
    $your_private_key_from_google_api_console,
    "sha256WithRSAEncryption"
);
$jwtSign = base64url_encode($jwtSig);

//{Base64url encoded JSON header}.{Base64url encoded JSON claim set}.{Base64url encoded signature}
$jwtAssertion = $jwtHeader.".".$jwtClaim.".".$jwtSign;
```

Comment: How can I get your_private_key_from_google_api_console from Google service account? The private file I've downloaded is a json with many info there

Comment: You should be able to find the "private_key" property in the JSON. `"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`. If it isn't there, try creating a "Service Account" in the Google IAM & Admin Console. Here is a guide on service account keys: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys

Comment: Make sure to click "+ Create Key" on the bottom after you click on or create your Service Account.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you need to add a code identifier in the header. Where is the problem in class?

```html
JWT::createJWT();

class JWT
{
    public static function createJWT()
    {
        function base64url_encode($data)
        {
            return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
        };
        $json = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/secrets.json');
        $secret = json_decode($json, true);
        $headers = ['alg' => 'RS256', 'typ' => 'JWT', $secret['private_key_id']];
        $headers_encoded = base64url_encode(json_encode($headers));
        $time = time();
        $lastTime = time() + 3600;
        $payload = [
            'iss' => $secret['client_email'],
            'sub' => $secret['client_email'],
            'aud' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/',
            'iat' => $time,
            'exp' => $lastTime
        ];
        $payload_encoded = base64url_encode(json_encode($payload));
        $key = $secret['private_key'];
        openssl_sign(
            "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded",
            $RSA256,
            $key,
            "sha256WithRSAEncryption"
        );
        $keyRSA256 = base64url_encode($RSA256);
        $JWT = "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded.$keyRSA256";

        $token = [
            'access_token' => $JWT,
            'lastTime' => $lastTime,
            'dostup' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
        ];

        $tokenJSON = json_encode($token, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/token.php', $tokenJSON, LOCK_EX);

        echo $tokenJSON;
    }
}
```

[JSON](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest:%7E:text=%7B%0A%C2%A0%20%22alg%22%3A%20%22RS256%22%2C%0A%C2%A0%20%22typ%22%3A%20%22JWT%22%2C%0A%C2%A0%20%22kid%22%3A%20%22abcdef1234567890%22%0A%7D%0A.%0A%7B%0A%C2%A0%20%22iss%22%3A%20%22123456%2Dcompute%40developer.gserviceaccount.com%22%2C%0A%C2%A0%20%22sub%22%3A%20%22123456%2Dcompute%40developer.gserviceaccount.com%22%2C%0A%C2%A0%20%22aud%22%3A%20%22https%3A//firestore.googleapis.com/%22%2C%0A%C2%A0%20%22iat%22%3A%201511900000%2C%0A%C2%A0%20%22exp%22%3A%201511903600%0A%7D)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34674144)